# Is a golang range in a for loop guaranteed to be evaluated only once?

Tags: for-loop, go, evaluation

In a software I'm working on, I see many loops that look like this:

```
for _, i := range strings.Split(s, ",") { ... }
```

I wanted to make sure that the range was only evaluated once since splitting a string is always costly.

Is there a rule in the documentation of golang about this?

Comment: For the Go rules documentation, read [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec). In particular: [For statements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://golang.org/ref/spec

> The range expression x is evaluated once before beginning the loop, with one exception: if at most one iteration variable is present and len(x) is constant, the range expression is not evaluated.

Comment: Does `_, i` count as 1 or 2 iteration variables?

Comment: The previous paragraph in that doc seems to imply that `_, i` would count as 2 iteration variables, which makes sense since it'd only avoid the evaluation when values are not important, just the length to return the indexes: _"As with an assignment, if present the operands on the left [...]; they denote the iteration variables. If the range expression is a channel, at most one iteration variable is permitted, otherwise there may be up to two. If the last iteration variable is the blank identifier, the range clause is equivalent to the same clause without that identifier."_